# Proving $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now,$\mathbb{Q} - \{x\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}-\{y,z\} $ are countable dense subsets without endpints, so they are $(g)$homeomorphic. Is
$f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ defined by $f(\{y,z\}) = \{x\}$. and
$f = g$ on $\mathbb{Q}-\{y,z\}$ continuous.

Comment: What's $\{y, z\}$ ?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: Some set of two distinct rationals.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $y<z$, and let $\alpha$ be any irrational less than $x$. Let

$$\begin{align*}
L&=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<y\}\;,\\
C&=\{q\in\Bbb Q:y<q<z\}\;,\\
R&=\{q\in\Bbb Q:z<q\}\;,\\
L'&=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<\alpha\}\;,\\
C'&=\{q\in\Bbb Q:\alpha<q<x\}\;,\text{ and}\\
R'&=\{q\in\Bbb Q:x<q\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

It’s possible to choose $g$ so that it’s an order-isomorphism that maps $L$ onto $L'$, $C$ onto $C'$, and $R$ onto $R'$. Now let $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any sequence in $C$ converging to $y$; then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges in $\Bbb R$ to $\alpha$ and hence has no limit in $\Bbb Q$. In particular, it does not converge to $x=f(y)$, so $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: :so there is no a continuous map sends $y,z$ to $x$ and bijective on the rest.

Comment: @Sobhi: That’s a different question. I just showed that the $f$ in your question does not have to be continuous. I think that with some work I can probably construct a continuous $f$ taking $y$ and $z$ to $x$ that is a homeomorphism on $\Bbb Q\setminus\{y,z\}$.

Comment: @Sobhi: And I now see that you’ve asked it as a separate question. I was able to construct such an $f$, and I’ve answered the other question with it.